# ListView redraw renderer for xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview where each row in listview items contain a heading, description and plus image. I am hiding initially, the description of each row. On clicking the plus image, the description of the clicked row will expand with the description. I am using MVVM for this. I checked Android and it is working fine. But for iOS, on clicking the + image of any row other than the last, it overlaps the items in the list view which is an issue. I assume that we may need to redraw the listview when the height gets changed for the loaded listview. Please help me in this.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.forms ?

Comment: Yes.. i am using  xamarin forms

Comment: do you have NotEvenRows set on the list?

Comment: HasUnevenRows="True" for list view. Note that it is working for Android and iOS it is getting overlapped.

Comment: @YuriS Hello, any updates on this?

Comment: can you share sample project?